# No php existe algum servidor embutido?

Tags: php, servidor

As vezes queremos rodar um simples script em PHP para realizar testes, porém não queremos gastar tempo instalando `wamp`, `xampp` ou mesmo instalando o `apache2` seguido do PHP.

Existe alguma maneira de rodar o script em PHP, com algum servidor simples, sem a necessidade de instalar algum das aplicação citadas acima.

Comment: Não entendi o -1 seguido do +1. KKK

Comment: Tambem não entendi, dei +1 pra nao ficar negativo. E como ja foi respondido existe sim.

Comment: Um amigo do chat não sabia dessa. Achei pertinente postá-la aqui pra que outras pessoas saibam que no PHP existe um servidor.

Answer (score 5):

Sim, existe uma maneira.

A partir da versão `5.4` o PHP oferece, na própria linguagem, um servidor embutido.

Basta rodar o seguinte código na linha de comando:

```
php -S localhost:9000
```

Isso fará que o PHP crie um pequeno servidor para rodar os seus scripts. A raiz da sua aplicação será considerada a pasta em que o comando foi executado.

Se você deseja especificar a pasta onde vai executar o script, basta utilizar a opção `-t`

Veja:

```
php -S localhost:9000 -t /var/www/stackoverlow
```

Veja mais sobre isso em [Manual do PHP - Servidor Web embutido](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.webserver.php)